# Get latest test case version through JAVA TestLink API

Tags: java, testlink

The task is to add test cases to the test plan along there execution. It is always needed to add the latest TC version, but API docs do not specify any method for this. Is there any way to get latest test case version via TestLink Java API properly? As the only solution I can think of is iteratively increase version by one, unless you start getting an exception. That would mean that previous version is the last.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked a question regarding the Test Case retrieval from Test Link, if you know the solution, please answer. The link to the question is:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17482/how-to-retrieve-automated-test-case-names-from-testlink

Thanks,
-Prasad

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Testlink Python API, but since both rely on XML for data exchange, this should work similarly in Java. I'm using the following code to retrieve the latest version of a testcase:

```
client = TestlinkAPIClient(SERVER_URL, DEV_KEY)
latestVersion = client.getTestCase("AB-001234")[0]['version']
```

`getTestCase` returns an array of results, that's why I use `[0]` to access the first element (since we only get one result because test IDs are unique). The result is a dictionary, and the desired value is accessible via the key 'version'. Hope this helps someone.